# selectList.SelectedValue is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I keep getting this error when I implement my code for a dropdown list.
Here is my code:

```
String sort = "";
String day_hire = "Daily hire rate";
String man_date = "Manufacturing date";
string man_n = "Manufacturer's name";

if (sl2.SelectedValue.ToString()== man_n)
{
    sort = "man.manufacturer_name";

}
else if (sl2.SelectedValue.ToString() == man_date)
{
    sort = "veh.manufacturing_date";
}
else if (sl2.SelectedValue.ToString() == day_hire) 
{
    sort = "veh.daily_hire_rate";
}
else
{
    sort = "veh.daily_hire_rate"; 
}
```

this is in constructor. In view I've got:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList ("sort",((SelectList)ViewData["selectOptions2"]))%>
```

it's a runtime error that says `sl2.SelectedValue.ToString()` is null. Please help

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say. It's a selectList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a POST, the selected value will be stored in the "sort" value, which you had declared here:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList ("sort",((SelectList)ViewData["selectOptions2"]))%>
```

So you need to do:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Whatever()
{
    var selectedItem = Request.Form["sort"] // Or however you want to pick up the value.
}
```

[This is a very good article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) which goes into more detail.

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem another way. I used FormCollection to retrieve the information from selectList.

Comment: Ahh yes, `FormCollection` is another way to get to the posted values.